# Text Box date value display in variant number, vba coding excel

Tags: excel, vba

Please provide some solution and guide me. i had wrote a userform in VBA excel code.
the problem is after i enter date format like 12/08/2020 into the sheets then i had did the edit button to edit the data but it display the date value in textbox is 44054 (date in sheet is 12/08/2020) .

How can i make the textbox display the value in 12/08/2020?

Thank you.

Comment: You probably need to change your VBA code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `CDate()` function.

Example: I have the value '44055' in cell A1

```
Public Sub tmp()
    a = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value
    b = CDate(a)
    MsgBox ("value a: " & a & vbCrLf & "value b: " & b)
End Sub
```

Returns a message box with:

value a:44055

value b:12/08/2020

Comment: But i need to show in textbox value is 12/08/2020. i had tried this code Me.TextBox12.Value = Format(Me.TextBox12.Value, "DD/MM/YYYY") but the textbox value still show out like 44054. Do you have another solution form you?